# Mplayer Fedora No video

Tags: fedora, mplayer

I have installed MPlayer. I have vaio with ATI graphics card. When I try to play movie file such as .avi, MPlayer GUI opens, but there is no video (just white GUI) I can see all the control buttons, it also plays the audio, but no video.

What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - it is user based.

Drop to a terminal and move into the (normally hidden) .mplayer directory with `cd .mplayer`

Check the dates and times of the files by an `ls -al`. Below is mine - note the date on the config file - it was when the video disappeared for me:

```
drwxrwxr-x    2 roger roger  4096 Jan 25  2009 . 
drwx--x--x. 153 roger roger 20480 Oct 27 23:22 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 roger roger    44 Jan 25  2009 config
-rw-rw-r--    1 roger roger  2881 Oct 27 23:22 gui.conf
-rw-rw-r--    1 roger roger    70 Oct 27 23:22 gui.history
-rw-rw-r--    1 roger roger    36 Oct 27 23:22 gui.pl
-rw-rw-r--    1 roger roger   838 Oct 27 23:22 gui.url
```

To fix it, simply delete the config file with: `rm config`

Try Mplayer and you should have video back.

Answer (score 0):

Aditya - Open the terminal and play the video using mplayer

`mplayer <location of video file>`

And copy paste the output messages onto [pastebin](http://pastebin.ca)  and post the pastebin link here.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following in a terminal:

```
su -c 'yum install xine* && yum install gstreamer*'
```